# How to ensure the files is an XML file

Tags: php, xml, multithreading, security, xml-parsing

I donot know much about files and its related security. I have a LOT of data in XML files which i am planning on parsing to put in the database. I get these XML files from 3rd party people. I will be getting minimum around 1000 files per day. So i will write a script to parse them to enter in our database. Now i have many questions regarding this.

1. I know how to parse a single file. And i can extend the logic to multiple files in a single loop. But.Is there a better way to do the same? How can i use multi threaded programming to parse the files simultaneously many of them. There will be a script which, given the file, parses the single file and outputs to database. How can i use this script to parse in multiple threads/parallel processing
2. The File as i said, Comes from a 3rd party site. So how can i be sure that there are no security loop holes. I mean, i dono much about file security. But what are the MINIMUM common basic security checks i need to take.(like sql injection and XSS in web programing are VERY basic)
3. Again security related: How to ensure that the incoming XML file is XML itself. I mean i can use the extension, But is there a possibility to inject scripts and make them run when i parse these files. And What steps should i take while parsing individual files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to [validate the XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_validation). This does two things:

1. Make sure it is "well-formed" - a valid XML document
2. Make sure it is "valid" - follows a schema, dtd or other definition - it has the elements and you expect to parse.

In [php5 the syntax](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1713#Heading13) for validating XML documents is:

- `$dom->validate('articles.dtd');`
- `$dom->relaxNGValidate('articles.rng');`
- `$dom->schemaValidate('articles.xsd');`

Of course you need an XSD (XML Schema) or DTD (Document Type Definition) to validate against.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to point 1, but it sounds fairly simple - each file can be parsed *completely* independently.

Points 2 and 3 are effectively about the contents of the file. Simply put, you can check that it's valid XML by parsing it and asking the parser to validate as it goes, and that's all you need to do. If you're expecting it to follow a particular DTD, you can validate it against that. (There are multiple levels of validation, depending on what your data is.)

XML files are just data, in and of themselves. While there are "processing instructions" available as XML, they're not instructions in quite the same way as direct bits of script to be executed, and there should be no harm in just parsing the file. Two potential things a malicious file could do:

- Try to launch a denial-of-service attack by referring to a *huge* external DTD, which will make the parser use large amounts of bandwidth. You can probably disable external DTD resolution if you want to guard against this.
- Try to take up significant resources just by being very large. You could always limit the maximum file size your script will handle.